# trying to use Symfony component and having name space issues

Tags: symfony

So i am starting a new project and want to use some of the Symfony Components. I have not used name spaces before with PHP, put i am familiar with the concept from my work in java.

i have this simple piece of code and when i run it i get the error:
**PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\CssSelector\XPath\Translator' not found in /home/me/scrapes/Symfony/Component/CssSelector/CssSelector/CssSelector.php on line 52**

I am thinking it my lack of knowledge of the name space thing. 
/home/me/scrapes/Symfony/Component/CssSelector/CssSelector/XPath/Translator.php does exist.

```
<?php
set_include_path('/home/me/html/inc');
require 'functions.php';
require 'Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler/Crawler.php';
require 'Symfony/Component/CssSelector/CssSelector/CssSelector.php';

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
use Symfony\Component\CssSelector\CssSelector;

$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addContent('<html><body><p>Hello World!</p></body></html>');
print $crawler->filter('body > p')->text();

curl_close($ch);    

require 'cleanup.php';
?>
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is caused because, if you look in the files you required (for example `Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler/Crawler.php`) you'll see that those files use their own `use` statements (to load other classes).

#### Namespaces

Let's start with the **namespaces**. A namespace is used to easily create classes with the same name in different packages. Let's say I have a package called `Foo` and a package called `Bar`. Both packages contain a `Client` class that is used to do some client work (one to call the Google Maps API for example and the other to call the Facebook Graph API). Let's also assume neither of the packages uses namespaces.

If I execute the following code:

```
<?php
require 'Foo/Client.php';
require 'Bar/Client.php';
```

This is not going to work, because both packages declare a `Client` class. Oops, how is PHP going to know which `Client` class to use if you do this?

```
<?php
$client = new Client();
```

It's not going to know which `Client` to use, so it gives up and throws an error.

If you use namespaces (declared using the `namespace` keyword in PHP at the top of your file, directly below `<?php`) you can prevent this from happening. The `Foo` package can create a `Client` class in the `Foo` namespace and the `Bar` package in the `Bar` namespace. Now we can
actually use both files and create a client:

```
<?php
require 'Foo/Client.php'
require 'Bar/Client.php'

$fooClient = new Foo\Client();
$barClient = new Bar\Client();
```

This will work fine.

I think you might have encountered the `Foo_Client` notation in older PHP libraries. This is an old way to create namespaces before PHP natively supported them.

"But", I hear you say, "it's quite cumbersome to write `Foo\Bar\Baz\Client()` every time I want to instantiated a class".

It is, and that's where the `use` keyword comes in. When using the `use` keyword, I can tell PHP I want to use a specific client and just use the class name, like so:

```
<?php
require 'Foo/Bar/Baz/Client.php'
use Foo\Bar\Baz\Client;

$client = new Client();
```

This will work, if you use the `use Foo\Bar\Baz\Client` statement, because you tell PHP "Okay, I want to use the `Client` class from the `Foo\Bar\Baz` namespace to be used when I use the `Client` class.

#### Autoloading

Now, what happens if you use a lot of different classes and you seperated them into several files (which you should do). You get a lot of different `require` and `use` statements on the top of a file. That's where **autoloading** comes in.

There has been a `spl_register_autoloader` function for quite some time in PHP. This function is used by PHP to find out which files to use when you instantiate a class that is not known because you did not `require` the file. This function is used both when creating a class, or, and this is the key part *when you `use` a class*.

And that's what's happening in your code. You don't have an autoloader registered that can translate the `use` statements in the files you required to actual class declarations.

#### Great, how do I fix it?

To fix it, I suggest you read up on the [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/) and [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). These people created standards (which you can follow but are not obliged to). To create easy to use libraries, such as the Symfony component. After you've done that, read up on [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/). After you've done this, you can drop the `require` statements from your code and use Composer to autoload all the classes you need.